# Printing and inserting selected row in treeview into tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have the following code to print and insert selected `treeview` row in an`entry` widget but am having challenges on how to do it.My `List profile` doesn't display the content correctly in the `treeview` , i want the year to appear under column specify for same as the month.

When i select the row it prints `('end',)`to my terminal and inserts `end` in my both `entry` widget and not the selected.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


profile = [("2012", "JANUARY"),
           ("2013", "FEBRUARY"),
           ("2014", "MARCH"),
           ("2015", "APRIL"),
           ("2016", "MAY")
           ]


def content(event):
    print(tree.selection()) # this will print the row inserted

    for nm in tree.selection():
        e1.insert(END, nm)
        e2.insert(END, nm)


root = Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("columns1","columns2" ), show="headings", 
selectmode="browse")
tree.heading("#1", text="YEAR")
tree.heading("#2", text="MONTH")
tree.insert("", 1, END, values=profile)

tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", content)
tree.pack()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to iterate over your `profile` list to populate the treeview:

```
for values in profile:
    tree.insert("", END, values=values)
```

What you were doing:

```
tree.insert("", 1, END, values=profile)
```

created one row, with item name 'end' and values the first two tuple of `profile`.

I guess that you want to insert the year of the selected row in `e1` and the month in `e2`. However, `tree.selection()` gives you the selected items' name, not the values, but you can get them with `year, month = tree.item(nm, 'values')`. So the `content` function becomes

```
def content(event):
    print(tree.selection()) # this will print the names of the selected rows

    for nm in tree.selection():
        year, month = tree.item(nm, 'values')
        e1.insert(END, year)
        e2.insert(END, month)
```

Comment: have been struggling for a while to answer this

Comment: see this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767101/how-to-update-only-selected-sqlite3-record-from-tkinter-treeview)@_4321 and help me out boss