# How to update only selected sqlite3 record from tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, treeview

Am trying to update `sqlite3` db selected in `tkinter treeview`, am able to insert the `row of the treeview selected` in the `entry` widget but when i update the record selected it updates all the records in the `sqlite3` db. I need your help to update only the record selected in the `treeview` but not all the records in the `sqlite3` db.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3


def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("TRIAL.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
First TEXT, Surname TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def Update():
    data1 = first_text.get()
    data2 = surname_text.get()

    for selected in tree.selection():
        e1.insert(0, selected) 
        e2.insert(0, selected)
        conn = sqlite3.connect("TRIAL.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?", (data1, data2))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


def get_selected_row(event):
    print(tree.selection())  # this will print the names of the selected rows
    for nm in tree.selection():
        content = tree.item(nm, 'values')
        e1.insert(tk.END, content[1])
        e2.insert(tk.END, content[2])  # this will insert in the entry after

connect()  #  this to create the db

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
                          # this will hide the first column
tree= ttk.Treeview(root, column=("column1", "column2", "column3"), 
show='headings')
tree.heading("#1", text="NUMBER") 
tree.heading("#2", text="FIRST NAME")
tree.heading("#3", text="SURNAME")
tree.pack()

tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", get_selected_row)

first_text = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=first_text)
e1.pack()
surname_text = tk.StringVar()
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=surname_text)
e2.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(text="EDIT PARTICULAR DATA", command=Update)
b2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am almost certain this was asked up to four days ago. Was that you?

Comment: yeaa am able to solve some of the issues,it left with updating only the selected record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't tell the db which record to update:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?", (data1, data2))
```

so all records are updated. You need to add the record id:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?  WHERE ID =?", (data1, data2, tree.set(selected, '#1')))
```

I found the answer on the website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm.