# Curse selection for treeview similar to listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tkinter-entry

In the past, I've taking Listbox values and input them into entry widgets. Now I need to do the same with a tree but the only help I found that is similar to what I want to do: [Printing and inserting selected row in treeview into tkinter entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754014/printing-and-inserting-selected-row-in-treeview-into-tkinter-entry-widget) is not working for me.
Basically I need to figure out how to modify what I normally do with listbox to work for a tree.

```
def dynamicPO(self):
    sql=("""SELECT(cast(Notes as nvarchar(max))) 'PO Number', POPY.AccountCode, POPY.Vendor, Items,FORMAT(([POAmount]),'C0') As 'PO AMOUNT', FORMAT(SUM([DailyCosts].DailyCost),'C0') AS 'COSTS TO DATE',FORMAT(POAmount  - SUM(DailyCosts.DailyCost), 'C0') 'Remaining Amount' FROM DailyCosts JOIN POPY ON DailyCosts.WellID = POPY.WellID AND DailyCosts.JobID = POPY.JobID AND (cast(DailyCosts.Notes as nvarchar(max)))= POPY.PONumber WHERE DailyCosts.WellID = ? and DailyCosts.JobID = ? GROUP BY (cast(DailyCosts.Notes as nvarchar(max))),POAmount,POPY.Vendor,POPY.Items,POPY.AccountCode, POPY.WellID, POPY.JobID ORDER BY POPY.Vendor""")
    self.cursor.execute(sql,[self.powellid_bx.get(),self.pojobid_bx.get(ACTIVE)])
    rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row) # it print all records in the database
        self.tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)

    self.tree= ttk.Treeview(self.tab4, column=("column1", "column2", "column3","column4", "column5", "column6", "column7"), show='headings')
    self.tree.grid(row=7, column = 0, columnspan =8, sticky = "NSEW")
    self.tree.heading("#1", text="PO Number")
    self.tree.heading("#2", text="Budget Code")
    self.tree.heading("#3", text="Vendor")
    self.tree.heading("#4", text="Items")
    self.tree.heading("#5", text="PO Amount")
    self.tree.heading("#6", text="Cost to Date")
    self.tree.heading("#7", text="Remaining PO Amount")

    self.tree.bind("<<TreeViewSelect>>", self.get_selected_PO)
```

## The code below works with listbox but unfortunatley tree does not have a curselection option

```
def get_selected_PO(self,event):
    global selected_tuple
    if self.tree.curselection():
        index = self.tree.curselection()[0]
        selected_tuple = self.tree.get(index)
        self.treepo_entry.insert('end', str(selected_tuple[0]))
        self.treevend_entry.insert('end', selected_tuple[1])
        self.treeitems_entry.insert('end', selected_tuple[2])
        self.treeamount_entry.insert('end', selected_tuple[3])
        self.treedate_entry.insert('end', selected_tuple[4])
        self.treecomments_entry.insert('end' , selected_tuple[5])
```

## I've treid to do something like this but to no avail

```
def get_selected_PO(self,event):
    for item in self.tree.selection():
        self.treepo_entry.insert(END,'row')
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the treeview? The method to get the selected items is documented.

Comment: I've checked it out but maybe I'm missing something. Would you mind giving me a hint to where to look?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview), the `selection` method will return you a list of identifiers for the selected elements. Even if you support only a single selection, this will be a list.

Also according to the documentation, you can use the `item` method to get all of the information for an item, in the form of a dictionary.

And finally, the event that is generated when the user selects an item is `<<TreeviewSelect>>`. Notice that the `v` is lowercase.

Here is fully working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("Column1", "Column2"))
        eframe = ttk.Frame(root)
        eframe.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.tree.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.e1 = ttk.Entry(eframe)
        self.e2 = ttk.Entry(eframe)
        self.e3 = ttk.Entry(eframe)

        self.e1.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.e2.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.e3.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=f"Item #{i}", values=(f"{i}: a", f"{i}: b"))

        self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.handle_selection)

    def handle_selection(self, event):
        self.e1.delete(0, "end")
        self.e2.delete(0, "end")
        self.e3.delete(0, "end")

        selection = self.tree.selection()
        if selection:
            item = self.tree.item(selection)
            self.e1.insert(0, item['text'])
            self.e2.insert(0, item['values'][0])
            self.e3.insert(0, item['values'][1])

Example()
tk.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot of tree with one row selected]